# Reference to @dynamic accessor fails to compile

Tags: objective-c, core-data, dynamic

This is my first use of the @dynamic keyword. I'm trying to use core data. I have a class referring to an object of NSManagedObject type. The object of NSManagedObject type was automatically created by XCode from an existing core data entity that I had set up.

The code will not compile because of an error at the line beginning 'Client.FirstName'. See the note in the comment on that line.

Since the reference is to a dynamic accessor, I am surprised that the compiler would flag this as a bad reference. It looks pretty simple, but I'm obviously missing something. I'm not sure what is wrong.

The code is this:

aTestClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>    

@interface aTestClass : NSObject {

}

- (void) foo;

@end
```

aTestClass.m

```
#import "aTestClass.h"
#import "Client.h"

@implementation aTestClass

- (void) foo {
    Client.FirstName = @"CompilerFail";  // Fails here: Property 'FirstName' not found in object of type 'Client'
}

@end
```

and the Client codes is this NSManagedObject, automatically generated by XCode 4.

Client.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Client : NSManagedObject {
//@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * FirstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * LastName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * Company;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* Jobs;

@end
```

Client.m

```
#import "Client.h"

@implementation Client
@dynamic FirstName;
@dynamic LastName;
@dynamic Company;
@dynamic Jobs;

- (void)addJobsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value {    
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"Jobs" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"Jobs"] addObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"Jobs" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [changedObjects release];
}

- (void)removeJobsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value {
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"Jobs" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"Jobs"] removeObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"Jobs" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [changedObjects release];
}

- (void)addJobs:(NSSet *)value {    
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"Jobs" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"Jobs"] unionSet:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"Jobs" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];
}

- (void)removeJobs:(NSSet *)value {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"Jobs" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"Jobs"] minusSet:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"Jobs" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value];
}

@end
```

Comment: It'd help greatly if you follow the naming conventions of the language;  classes start with capital letters.  Methods & properties start with lower case letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the complete code?

> Client.FirstName = @"CompilerFail";

`Client` as in "the class named Client"? Or is `Client` a instance of the class `Client`?

That's why instance variables should not start with an uppercase letter. It's confusing.

Your code should probably be something like this.

```
Client *someClient = ...
someClient.firstName = @"Foo";
```

You can see exactly what is a class and what is a variable or property.

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem, basically -- forgetting to instantiate from the class. I have it straightened out now.